# Navigate from a secure domain to a non-secure subdomain without warning?

Tags: ssl, browser, ssl-certificate

If the user is on a https://example.com and clicks on a link which leads to http://subdomain.example.com could it generate any sort of warning?

I prefer to keep the subdomains non-secure, since it saves money on certificates, but a warning would be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, older versions of Internet Explorer issued a warning when switching from a secured page to a non-secured page.

You can also get a warning (and even be marked insecured) from more recent browser (Google Chrome, Firefox...) if you include content from your subdomains (e.g. static.mydomain.com) since you would put insecure data into a secure page.

One way to save money on certificates is to use x509v3 extension `SubjectAlternativeName` (SAN) which lets you specify domain names for which the certificate is valid.

This is an extract of the SAN DNS names from google.com certificate :

- google.com
- *.2mdn.net
- *.android.com
- *.appengine.google.com
- *.au.doubleclick.net
- *.cc-dt.com
- *.cloud.google.com
- *.doubleclick.com
- *.doubleclick.net
- *.url.google.com
- *.youtube-nocookie.com
- *.youtube.com
- ...

I think most certificate providers will let you choose your domain names (except wildcards for some).

Finally, if you don't want to spend any money on securing your website, I suggest you try one of these :

- StartSSL: free certificates covering your top domain and one subdomain (certificate revocation is not free !)
- The `letsencrypt` initiative, providing free certificates for everyone, now trusted by everybody

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info! I think we're good then since we will only put a link to the subdomain on the secure domain, and not include any content. Also we don't support older browsers anyway. I will look into SAN to see if we can support the subdomain from our domain certificate.